Has anyone in The Walking Dead ever survived a zombie bite without turning, except through amputation?
Has anyone in The Walking Dead ever been confirmed to have survived being bitten by a zombie through any means other than having the limb amputated immediately after a bite, without them expiring and turning soon after?
Either in the original source material, the TV show, or any of the canonical spinoffs?

https://walkingdead.fandom.com/wiki/Category:Bite_Survivors - A quick glance at the wiki suggests not

No, surviving a zombie bite in The Walking Dead is only possible through timely amputation
In The Walking Dead universe, all characters who have managed to survive zombie bites have done so by having the affected limb amputated shortly after being bitten. This is the only known method that prevents the infection from spreading to the rest of the body, effectively saving the bitten person's life.
Across various The Walking Dead media, several characters have been confirmed to survive a zombie bite, all through amputation: Dale (The Walking Dead comics), Hershel Greene (The Walking Dead TV series), Clementine (The Walking Dead: The Telltale Series), Lilly Caul (The Walking Dead comics and novel series), Connie (The Walking Dead comics), Elton Ortiz (The Walking Dead: World Beyond), Lydia (The Walking Dead TV series), Virginia (Fear the Walking Dead), and Alicia Clark (Fear the Walking Dead).
You may also be interested in why zombie bites are fatal if the affected limb isn't amputated, especially considering that it has been revealed that every human being is already infected with the zombie virus. If so, see "Why are Walker bites in the Walking Dead fatal?"

According to Screen Rant, nuclear radiation can cure the zombie infection received from a bite, but the amount of radiation required is eventually lethal to the patient.  Lose, lose.
Quoting from the article:

The key line comes in Fear The Walking Dead season 8, episode 2, in
which June discusses a bitten patient, admitting, "It stopped the
infection, but the amount of radiation that it took just made things
worse for her."

From The Walking Dead Fandom Wiki:

After joining PADRE, June began performing experiments on a potential
cure to the active infection of the Wildfire Virus using radiation.
Although successful in stopping the infection from the bites
themselves, June's treatment was fatal to her test subjects, driving
June to flee PADRE and go rogue until she was forced back into her
work years later.


This explains how you could, but the question is whether anyone has. As far as I'm aware, the radiation cure hasn't cured anyone.

The quote indicates the patient was cured of the bite, but later died from radiation poisoning.

I think the problem here is the inconsistency in how the infection is portrayed, sometimes it's stated to be present in all humans, and other times it seems to be transferred from the bite itself.

@Valorum Isn't the quote "we're all infected"?

@AaarghZombies - Hence the inconsistency

@AaarghZombies - It also wouldn't explain why a bite is so deadly. Antibiotics are pretty effective nowadays

@Valorum, I don't remember where I heard it, but I think that the answer is that Zombie bites carry an active form of the virus that infects and kills the victim, and their death activates the virus that they're already infected with. Which is why when people die through any means they become zombies. The infection that they already have activates on death and turns them. The creator said, after the franchise had been completed, that it was an alien virus.
